# C# Multiple conditions

Tags: c#

To put it simply I would like to know if there is a way I can have multiple conditions to trigger a if statement.

To add to that the program I am working on will be for toner cartridge inventory management, and I want it to send an e-mail if our reserves of a particular colour is low. The code to send a e-mail is quite long to I want to avoid doing it in 4 different statements, such as:

```
if (k toner is low)
{
send mail
}

else if (C toner is low)
{
send mail
}

else if (M toner is low)
{
send mail
}

else if (Y toner is low)
{
send mail
}
```

so what I basically want is:

```
if (K or C or Y or M toner is low)
{
Send mail
}
```

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: Use [`||` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx) `if( c == low || M == low || y == low)`

Comment: Please do not use SO as a technique for learning the absolute *basics* of a language new to you.  Please learn via a class, a book, a tutorial, etc., and come here when due diligence has failed to yield a useful solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, you're just looking for the [`||` (conditional-OR) operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx):

```
if (kTonerIsLow || cTonerIsLow || ...) 
{
    SendEmail();
}
```

Note that the operator is short-circuiting - so if `kTonerIsLow` is true, it won't evaluate `cTonerIsLow`, etc. If you use `|` instead, it will still work - but it will evaluate both operands unconditionally.

Additionally, this comment struck me:

> The code to send a e-mail is quite long to I want to avoid doing it in 4 different statements

That suggests you should probably pull it out into a separate method anyway.

Comment: About the short-circuiting: it's the same as in the `if-elseif-elseif-elseif` construction used in the question example. The `|` operator will then be the same as multiple `if`-statements.

Comment: @Adimeus: Yes to your first sentence - no to your second. With multiple `if` statements, you'd get as many emails as "true conditions"... whereas with `if (a | b | c)` it will only call `SendEmail` once even if all three conditions are true.

Comment: @Adimeus If the conditions have no side-effects (which they don't, in this case), then using `|` is functionally the same as `||`

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, offcourse. Good point, though my reference to "the same" was more aimed at the evaluation of the different variables using `if-elseif` vs `||` and `|` as opposed to what happens once it's been evaluated.

Comment: Ah, of course! Im not with it today and completely blanked about methods, ill try doing the code to send the e-mail as a method and then just do 4 small if/if else statements and call the e-mail method each time.

Answer (score 1):

@Habib, @Jon

`||` Operator change business logic here. Lets assume that You want to send email when more than one toner is low, using `||` You will only send email with information than only one of the toners is low whether other toners are in same the same condition.

To solve this problem You can send information about all toners in one email

-or-

Create array of toners and then iterate through them checking if one of them is low:

```
foreach(toner in Toners)
{
  if (toner.IsLow)
     SendEmail(toner);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on dzaba's idea of an list of Printers:

```
 var printers = new Printer[] {...};
 if (printers.Any(p=>p.Toner.IsLow))
      sendEmail();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following format to solve your problem:

```
if (K is low || C is low || Y is low || M is low)
{
    Send mail
}
```